# Piecemeal training NaiveBayesClassifier (NLTK)

Tags: nltk, bayesian, text-classification

I have a lot of text data and I'd like to perform classification. I get this data incrementally by chunks (e.g. 500 exemplar).
I'd like to perform training NaiveBayesClassifier in NLTK with these chunks, but do piecemeal training.

Can I perform training NaiveBayesClassifier with one chuck, and after it use for training next chunk etc?

I can't find answer on this question in documentation.

Comment: what does piecemeal training mean?

Comment: For example: firstly, I have only 500 exemplars of training data, but after some time I'll have another (new) 500 exemplars of training data etc.
But I don't want wait while I get all of data (because it is expensive by time and memory space).
So, I'd like train classifier with one chunk of data, after some time use for training next chunk of data etc.

Comment: this looks relevant: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs12555-011-0099-1 but i would love to see a real python implementation though =)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the NLTK wrapper for scikit-learn and use the Naive Bayes implementation that scikit-learn offers. This one has support for doing partial fit, which does exactly what you want: train on only a part of the data at a time.

References: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I can think of:

1. Periodically retrain the classifier on the new data. You'd
   accumulate new training data in a corpus (that already contains the
   original training data), then whenever you get your next chunk,
   retrain & reload the classifier. This is probably the simplest
   solution.
2. Externalize the internal model, then update it manually. The
   `NaiveBayesClassifier` can be created directly by giving it a
   `label_prodist` and a `feature_probdist`. You could create these
   separately, pass them in to a `NaiveBayesClassifier`, then update
   them whenever new data comes in. The classifier would use this new
   data immediately. You'd have to look at the train method for details
   on how to update the probability distributions for your specific
   case/needs.

If you're going with option 2 **and** you don't mind sacrificing a *little* speed for the sake of horizontal scalability, you could persist the models in Redis by creating a `ProbDistI` subclass that uses a Redis Hash for storage/lookup. Then you don't have to do any pickling of the corpus, and the classifier is always "on".

Answer (score -1):

Weka has an updateable Naive Bayes implementation.

Comment: This answer has next to no details. Can you expand on it?